# SVG transform scale is not applied

Tags: css, svg

I've included an inline svg in the html. My goal is to identify the individual stars and apply a "twinkle" effect as a keyframe. 
I noticed there are inline style attributes for its transform properties.

I changed the `transform-origin` of the individual star, `#star` to `transform-origin: 50% 50%` and added a `transform: scale(1.2)`, just to test a simple scaling effect.

For some reason, I don't see the transform being applied when I hover over `#star` element. The star disappears on hover.

Heres a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/johnnyginbound/pen/NaJaOv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `transform:scale()` to `#star:hover polygon` this should change the size of the polygons within the group.

```
#star:hover polygon{
 transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/jGJGJz?editors=1100)